# Jquery validate and default text

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to find a way to easily add default values to form which is using jquery validate plugin. I searched and didn't find anything useful, and the last similar question is one year old.
So, to ask again, is there easy way to add default values to form without messing with jquery validate code.
And of course, default values should disappear  when user start to type inside the field.

Edit: I see that question is little confusing, so here is better explanation. I want to add default text to form, and i want validation plugin to ignore that default value. I know i can add method that will check if value is default value, but since form is really big, i would prefer some other solution. Like some plugin that places default text above input field, so if form gets submitted with that filed not filled by user, it appears to validate plugin as empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just use that as attractiveness, you can just use placeholder attribute, `<input name="search" type="text" placeholder="Enter some keywords..." />`

Comment: This is what i need. Thanks, and thanks everyone for answers.

Comment: +1 for HTML5. If the browser doesn't support it, it just doesn't show.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <input type="text" name="user" id="user" value="YOUR DEFUALT VALUE" />
```

or

```
 $("#user").attr("value", "YOUR DEFAULT VALUE");
```

Just use the above code in dom ready and it should be fine I would think.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the message that is seen after validation fails then you can do something like this. If you are talking a default value for the textbox itself look at the answer from @Caimen.

```
$("form").validate({
    rules: {FirstName: "required defaultCheck"},
    messages: {
          FirstName: "First name is required"
)};
```

Even though you've selected your answer this might help someone.
If you want the validator to ignore the default text which is what I think you wanted all along you can do this.

```
 $.validator.addMethod(
            'defaultCheck', function (value, element) {
                if (element.value == element.defaultValue) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
  });
```

Comment: +1 here. I realized that this is all you should use for handling default values. Why clear a default value out? Shouldn't your default value be a valid value that the user may want to use?

Comment: Well, i want to do something like value="write something...", and it should disappear when user start typing. I know how to do this, so it is no a problem. Problem is, if user dont type anything, validate plugin thinks that "write something..." is valid value (and it is, but should not be).

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on previous answer:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="user" id="user" value="YOUR DEFUALT VALUE" />
```

You should not clear default values from form fields.

Comment: I know that :) The thing is, when form is submitted, jquery validate plugin thinks that default value is correct value, and allow submitting of form.

Comment: the default value should be a valid value.

Comment: Forgot that enter enters comment :). I know i can write custom validate rule, but i am thinking that there must be easier way, since my form is huge and very complicated.

Comment: I think you should reconsider why you want to clear out a default value on form submit. I would go with the solution @Jack gave.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
<input name="firstName" value="First Name" defaultValue="First Name">
```

and then in the validation:

```
if(object.value != object.defaultValue)
  // validation
```